# How to instantiate AbstractSourceLookupDirector?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

I'm writing a plugin for Eclipse Juno, I want to make use of class AbstractSourceLookupDirector. When I look at the API it says it has a constructor, but when I use following statement in my code, it says "cannot instantiate type AbstractSourceLookupDirector"

AbstractSourceLookupDirector srclookupDir = new AbstractSourceLookupDirector();

Could you please let me know how to make use of AbstractSourceLookupDirector. 
Ref: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/core/sourcelookup/AbstractSourceLookupDirector.html

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is an Abstract class, you can't instantiate abstract classes in Java.
What you need to do is configure an extension point org.eclipse.debug.core.sourceLocators
and have your class extend AbstractSourceLookupDirector
An example is given in the juno docs
http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_debug_core_sourceLocators.html