# Eclipse custom source locator plugin for debug

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to implement a custom source locator like described in this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18084510/8315843

I imagine other types of source locations than usual archive or folder, such as online source or decompiled source.

The plugin.xml of my eclipse plug-in looks like:

```xml
<plugin>
  <extension point="org.eclipse.debug.core.sourceLocators">
   <sourceLocator
    id="com.mypackage.debug.core.sourceLocators.MySourceLocator"
    class="com.mypackage.debug.core.sourceLocators.MySourceLocator"
    name="My Source Locator">
   </sourceLocator>
  </extension>
</plugin>
```

For now the implementation does not do anything, I've just set breakpoints on every method to ensure it triggers when I click on a breakpoint in the breakpoint view or on a stack frame.

```java
package com.mypackage.debug.core.sourceLocators;

import org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException;
import org.eclipse.debug.core.ILaunchConfiguration;
import org.eclipse.debug.core.model.IPersistableSourceLocator;
import org.eclipse.debug.core.model.IStackFrame;

public class MySourceLocator implements IPersistableSourceLocator {

    @Override
    public Object getSourceElement(IStackFrame stackFrame) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMemento() throws CoreException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void initializeFromMemento(String memento) throws CoreException {
    }

    @Override
    public void initializeDefaults(ILaunchConfiguration configuration) throws CoreException {
    }
}
```

I debug as an Eclipse application, I create a project with a library that contains an empty Main class with empty main method and a breakpoint on main method. When I click on the breakpoint or when I debug Main as a java application, it just shows "Class File Editor" and "Source not found", none of the breakpoints of MySourceLocator were hit.

I found other sources of infomation where, but not enough details for me to start and the thread is much too old to kick in:

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/366861/

> Try looking at ISourceLookupParticipant and ISourceLookupDirector
> (specifically the JavaSourceLookupDirector). It sound to me like you
> would want to add your own participant to the Java director, which you
> can do by calling ISourceLookupDirector #addParticipants(...).
>
> To get the Java director you have to a bit more work, you will need to
> get the ILaunch from the frame (thread, etc) and ask for its
> ISourceLocator (in the Java case it is an ISourceLookupDirector). You
> would probably want to attach your participant to any new and existing
> Java launches, which you can do with the help of the ILaunchManager.

The OP seemed to understand exactly what to do with that much information but infortunately didn't post any details.

Comment: Were you clicking on different parts of the tree in the Debug view while debugging Main, i.e. the sort of actions that would send your class a stack frame? Does your Eclipse Application launch configuration clear its configuration space so that your plugin.xml changes won't be cached from before you made them?

Comment: My custom source locator is present in `fSourceLocators` map in `LaunchManager`, and the one with id `org.eclipse.jdt.launching.sourceLocator.JavaSourceLookupDirector` is selected instead, but does that means that my custom source locator has to be defined with id `org.eclipse.jdt.launching.sourceLocator.JavaSourceLookupDirector` ?